# Select Top X users based on their best Y scores, sorted by SUM(score)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, a table of users and a table of submissions

Users:

```
___id_____name____
   1   |  hello
   2   |  world
   3   |  foo
   4   |  bar
      ...
   50  |  peter
```

Submissions

```
___id_____userid______score___
   1   |    1    |    40
   2   |    2    |    60
   3   |    4    |    30
   4   |    12   |    60
   5   |    43   |    40
   6   |    3    |    100
   7   |    3    |    90
   8   |    34   |    60
   9   |    4    |    30
   10  |    3    |    50
   11  |    2    |    60
   12  |    2    |    10
   13  |    1    |    20
   14  |    4    |    70
           ...
   100 |    34   |    70
```

What I wish to do is obtain a set of 10 records that is ordered by a summation of each user's top 20 (or less) scores. ie. the Top 10 users based on the sum of their top 20 (or less) scores. The "or less" is for cases where some users may not have 20 submissions, but their sum of scores is still higher.

eg User A has only 15 submissions of total 2000 points, vs User B with 28 submissions, but his top 20 scores total only 1800 points. User A will be selected and/or ranked higher than B.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: User A? Who he? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There are 50 users in my example. User A and B are just 2 of them.